# Call rendering from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, render

I have a rails application with 3 controllers :

`categories`, `subcategories`, `all`

The two firsts fetch data from the db and render it via

```
render "list"
```

The last one should get the result of the first controller, the result of the second one and render them.

Simplified example :

```
# categories_controller.rb
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        render "list"
    end
end 

# subcategories_controller.rb
class SubcategoriesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        render "list"
    end
end 

# all_controller.rb
class AllController < ApplicationController
    def index
        # should render the both and join them
    end
end 

# list.html.erb
this is the list
```

Result :

```
/category
=> "this is the list "

/subcategory
=> "this is the list "

/all
=> "this is the list this is the list "
```

I tried to call

```
 render "subcategory"
 render "subcategory/index"
```

But nothing seems to work.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks,

---

A previous approach was the following :

```
# categories_controller.rb
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
    def self.getAll
        return Category.all
    end
    def index
        @data = CategoriesController.getAll
        # some logic here
        render "list"
    end
end 

# subcategories_controller.rb
class SubcategoriesController < ApplicationController
    def self.getAll
        return Category.all
    end
    def index
        @data = SubcategoriesController.getAll
        # some logic here
        render "list"
    end
end 

# all_controller.rb
class AllController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @categoriesData = CategoriesController.getAll
        @subcategoriesData = SubcategoriesController.getAll
        render 'all'
    end
end 

# list.html.erb
<%= @data %>

# all.html.erb
<%= @categoriesData %>
<%= @subcategoriesData %>
```

But I have to rewrite a part of logic that is already there ...

Comment: You can't render twice in the controller I don't think.  Why not use partials for category and subcategory and then render both of them in the view in the all controllers index action?

Comment: I tried to use the `render_to_string` method and then merge the two. A partial already exist, this example was for simplifying the question but I can  update it if you think it's worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly build the output that you need in the `all` controller action, rather than trying to join the outputs of other actions.

Two approaches:

1. Retrieve the items you want with two database calls, join them together into one big set of list items, then render the list as in the other actions.

   ```
   class AllController < ApplicationController
       def index
           categories = Categories.all
           sub_categories = Subcategories.all
           @all = categories + sub_categories
       end
    end
   ```
2. Retrieve both sets of data, make the `list.html` page call a partial called `_sub_list.html` or something, then have a new template for the `all` page called `all.html`, which renders the new partial twice, once for each set of data.

   ```
   class AllController < ApplicationController
       def index
           @categories = Categories.all
           @sub_categories = Subcategories.all
       end
    end
   ```

To reuse logic across controllers. use a concern:

```
module SharedLogic
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def useful_function
    # some code...
  end
end

class SubcategoriesController < ApplicationController
  include SharedLogic

  def index
    @data = SubcategoriesController.getAll
    # some logic here
    useful_function

    render "list"
  end
end
```

Comment: Your 1. was my first approach, I had an `all.html.erb`  that was called with all the data inside an object and then rendering the other parts from here . But there is a part of logic that I want to reuse from the two controllers. So I thought that using directly their response (as I use them anyway) was a better approach.

Comment: Use a separate function in the controller to share logic. Better yet, use a service object: https://sporto.github.io/blog/2012/11/15/a-pattern-for-service-objects-in-rails/

Comment: Reading the article, meanwhile I updated my question with my previous approach

Comment: Another alternative that may work for you is to use concerns to add the same functions to many controllers: https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3372-put-chubby-models-on-a-diet-with-concerns

Comment: I don't think a concerns will fit, but thanks for the idea though